# convert a String (numeric) in a Int append array - Swift

Tags: swift

I pull data from the database. The data I have taken: 9.0000,5.0000,5.000. I want to add them to the int array. I pull it out as a string when I pull it from the database. In the output of the current code: digits [9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
digits [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
digits [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]

```
    var fiyatArray = [Int]()

  @objc func CEK(){
  if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                        for review in baslik {
                             if let soru_baslik = review["DAV.FIYAT"] as? String {
                                 let s = soru_baslik

                                let digits = s.compactMap{Int(String($0))}

                                self.fiyatArray.append(contentsOf: digits)
                                print("digits", digits)
                                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                   self.collectionVi.reloadData()
                                 } } } }
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code? If `soru_baslik` is a `String` which holds what value? "9.0000" ? If so, why the `compactMap()` on it? What do you think it is doing? Give us the value of `review["DAV.FIYAT"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `compactMap` if `s` contains a single value, instead you can do

```
if let d = Double(s), let i = Int(exactly: d) {
    self.fiyatArray.append(contentsOf: i)
}
```